# Как делать записи в файл с новой строки?

Tags: c#

Как делать записи в файл с новой строки ?

```
File.AppendAllText("log.txt", "текст1");
File.AppendAllText("log.txt", "текст2");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну например

```
File.AppendAllText("log.txt", "текст1" + "\n");
```

или там

```
File.AppendAllText("log.txt", "текст1" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: "текст1" + "\n" и так "текст1\n" - это не одно и тоже ? Я пробовал так "текст1\n" не получалось(

Comment: @Vipz: Это одно и то же. Если ваш текстовый редактор не понимает `\n`, попробуйте `Environment.NewLine` (оно произведёт `\r\n`).

Comment: Действительно редактор не видел - использовал блокнот там было всё в одну строку, а в Notepad++ всё как надо. Спасибо что не прошли мимо, щас бы лбом долбился и не понимал почему \n игнорируется

Comment: @Vipz `\r` - возврат "каретки" в начало строки; `\n` - перевод на новую строку. В Windows исторически сложилось, что переносом строки является `\r\n`. Некоторые текстовые редакторы, такие как "Блокнот" разбивают текст именно по этой последовательности. Более продвинутые, такие как Notepad++, довольствуются только `\n`. Для себя ты можешь использовать любой формат. Но лучше следовать правилам той ОС, в которой ты работаешь. Для этого есть `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @Vipz: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.

Answer (score 4):

```
using (var tw = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
{
     tw.WriteLine("текст1");
     tw.WriteLine("текст2");
}
```